# How boost chance of interviews despite a short experience on resume

Tags: interviewing, recruiting

If I am laid off by a company after 6 months because of a financial crisis of this company (they are currently cutting  experienced/expensive people to replace them with junior or intern positions), how should I state this Job experience/issue on my resume while I am applying for new  jobs and I am unemployed? 
Basically what should I write next to the six months period e.g January -June.... Laid off because of a crisis? Or that  I voluntary quit? Or nothing, but only the length of the position? I Am afraid it may create some problems and will not get any interview.

Thank you all for sharing your opinion.

Comment: So they replaced someone with 6 months experience with a Junior? How can one possibly be more junior than that?

Comment: Thank you Prinz I will try to go in your direction. @Laurent.S I have 7 years of experience, so my position was quite high and well paod. To save cost they are fire-bombing people that earn more to replace them with people that cost less.

Answer (score 3):

### Accomplishments

Instead of looking at this as a negative, **turn it into a positive.**

The purpose of a resume is to provide the reader with reasons ***why*** they would want to hire you - not a list of what you did.

Therefore, it is important to emphasize your accomplishments/awards/recognitions in each job --- and to map those same items to the job for which you are applying.

Take some time, and think about your accomplishments and awards you received during this six month period and list them.  Then, think about the job you want, and see what matches your strengths.  Emphasize those matches first.

(And do the same for your other jobs).

Because most people just list their job duties and nothing more, your resume will stand out, and will draw the attention of the resume reader to your strengths, giving you a better chance of not only getting an interview, but the job.